# ¿Es una mala practica colocar etiquetas HTML en mayúscula?

Tags: html, html5, web, buenas-prácticas

Muy buenas, tengo la duda con respecto a la declaración de las etiquetas HTML en mayúscula, ya que he visto que al interactuar en JavaScript con el DOM debemos escribir las etiquetas en Mayúscula.
Se que lo mas común es ver la estructura HTML en minúscula, sin embargo, tengo la incertidumbre de que si las escribiera en mayúsculas, ¿tendría algún problema en el futuro?.

Comment: Las etiquetas HTML y sus atributos son "case insensitive", es decir, da igual si usas mayúsculas, minúsculas o una combinación de ellos. Por convención, se usa minúsculas, pero en realidad los navegadores parsean lo que sea. @MauricioContreras ¿Qué especificación es esa? [La especificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/documents.html#case-insensitivity) dice claramente que es case insensitive.

Comment: Sí podrías tener problemas para desarrollar, hay navegadores que no interpretan etiquetas en mayúscula, la gran mayoría sí, pero siempre hay que apuntar a realizar un código estándar que abarque una correcta interpretación en la gran mayoría de navegadores. Si usas minúsculas para tus etiquetas te será más fácil leer tu código, incluso vas hacerlo más rápido, porque tener mayúsculas todo el tiempo... cansa.

Comment: Pero dado que tu pregunta dice exclusivamente si es mala práctica. Sí lo es. Y además se ve horrible. Intenta siempre seguir las buenas prácticas y patrones, sobre todo para cuando trabajes en equipo. No porque "se pueda hacer" significa que está bien.

Comment: Esta pregunta genera debate y opinión lejos de dar una respuesta concreta como tal. En efecto si es de mala practica, pero en nada afecta la funcionalidad del código, mas bien es un asunto de formalidad, visualización y normatividad.

Comment: Información de la etiqueta "buenas-prácticas": _(...) No preguntes si algo es o no es una buena práctica ya que eso es pedir opiniones, más bien pregunta cosas concretas como: ¿En qué casos se consideraría una mala práctica X? o ¿Por qué X error me indica que es mala práctica Y?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente **HTML** no reconoce entre mayúsculas o minúsculas (case insensitive), así que si decides escribir en mayúsculas no tendrás problemas, pero se considera una buena práctica que las etiquetas estén en minúsculas, pero si quieres escribir las etiquetas en mayúsculas debes mantener esa práctica por todo tu proyecto aunque no afecte en nada ya que si se decide usar estilo con las etiquetas es bueno tener un orden en todo.
Este articulo puede aclarar aun más tu duda: [¿Son las etiquetas html 5 sensibles a mayusculas y minusculas?](https://tecnonautas.net/son-las-etiquetas-html-5-sensibles-a-mayusculas-y-minusculas/)